# Julia plot / statsplot does show default labels instead of column names

Tags: dataframe, julia, plots.jl, pluto.jl

My Julia plot does show default labels `y1` and `y2` instead of column names `a` and `b`.

```
using DataFrames, Plots, Statplots

df_test = DataFrame(a = 0:10, b = 20:30, c = 30:40)
@df df_test plot(:a, [:b, :c])
```

[image: Julia Plot]

Any suggestions how to solve the issue without explicitly naming the labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the second argument as a 1-row matrix to get what you want:

```
@df df_test plot(:a, [:b :c])
```

(note that between `:b` and `:c` there is no comma - only a space)

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me, except when I plot just one column (i.e. : a of :b). I tried with and without square brackets. Any suggestions how to solve that?

Comment: The second argument needs to be a 1-row matrix, and the syntax to get it is e.g. `@df df_test plot(:a, hcat(:b))`.